# How to tell if append created a new underlying array

Tags: arrays, go, slice

Is it possible to tell if the `append` builtin function created a new underlying array?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Go deliberately abstracts that away for you.

Comment: See [When does Go allocate a new backing array to slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041641/when-does-go-allocate-a-new-backing-array-to-slice/55042122#55042122) and [Why exactly is there a CAPACITY parameter when creating a slice in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782079/why-exactly-is-there-a-capacity-parameter-when-creating-a-slice-in-golang/54782127#54782127).

Comment: @Dai I like playing around with everything I can when i'm learning a new language -- helps me learn better and faster

Comment: @icza Thanks for the sources, although I'm well aware of both when a new array is allocated and how to use the capacity parameter builtin, and it's not quite what i was asking -- just trying to find out how to tell if it happened. Perhaps as an interview question for Go candidates?

Comment: @aryzing The answers contain info to tell when a new backing array is allocated.

Comment: Please keep in mind that while the question might sound ridiculous to the more experienced out there, it does serve as a valuable learning exepreince. As a newcomer to go, I'm feeling quite unwelcome to the community, which is in line with this year's "feeling welcome" stats https://blog.golang.org/survey2018-results. I don't understand what is so fundamentally wrong with the question to deserve the downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look for the memory pointer of the first element.

It will change if the internal capacity is scaled-up following power-of-two steps.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    sl := make([]int, 0, 4)
    sl = append(sl, []int{1,2}...)  
    fmt.Printf("%#v<-%v # same pointer address to the slice length 2 with capacity 4\n", &sl[0], len(sl))
    sl = append(sl, []int{1,2}...)  
    fmt.Printf("%#v<-%v # same pointer address to the slice length 2 with capacity 4\ncapacity will change from the next append on:\n", &sl[0], len(sl))
    for i:=0; i<10; i++{
        sl = append(sl, 1)
        fmt.Printf("%#v<-len(%v) cap(%v)\n", &sl[0], len(sl), cap(sl))
    }
    for i:=0; i<10; i++{
        sl = append(sl, sl...)
        fmt.Printf("%#v<-len(%v) cap(%v)\n", &sl[0], len(sl), cap(sl))
    }
}

will print:
(*int)(0x414020)<-2 # same pointer address to the slice length 2 with capacity 4
(*int)(0x414020)<-4 # same pointer address to the slice length 2 with capacity 4
capacity will change from the next append on:
(*int)(0x450020)<-len(5) cap(8)
(*int)(0x450020)<-len(6) cap(8)
(*int)(0x450020)<-len(7) cap(8)
(*int)(0x450020)<-len(8) cap(8)
(*int)(0x432080)<-len(9) cap(16)
(*int)(0x432080)<-len(10) cap(16)
(*int)(0x432080)<-len(11) cap(16)
(*int)(0x432080)<-len(12) cap(16)
(*int)(0x432080)<-len(13) cap(16)
(*int)(0x432080)<-len(14) cap(16)
(*int)(0x456000)<-len(28) cap(32)
(*int)(0x458000)<-len(56) cap(64)
(*int)(0x45a000)<-len(112) cap(128)
(*int)(0x45c000)<-len(224) cap(256)
(*int)(0x45e000)<-len(448) cap(512)
(*int)(0x460000)<-len(896) cap(1024)
(*int)(0x462000)<-len(1792) cap(2048)
(*int)(0x464000)<-len(3584) cap(4096)
(*int)(0x468000)<-len(7168) cap(8192)
(*int)(0x470000)<-len(14336) cap(16384)
```

(note: if looking at the unsafe.Pointer to the slice the pattern of change is less obvious)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, compare the capacity before and after:

```
before := cap(myArray)
myArray = append(myArray, newValue)
after := cap(myArray)
fmt.Printf("before: %d, after: %d", before, after)
```

The better question would be, why do you need to? Your code really shouldn't care if a new backing array was created or not.

Playground demo: https://play.golang.org/p/G_ZfrLfEpWb

Comment: Indeed a good question, just not the one I'm asking ;) B/c I like to play with the far reaches of a language while learning it, and it may be an interesting question during interviews to see how Go candidates react.